# deletion from Set iterator

Tags: java, iterator

Could someone explain to me why the following doesn't work (runways is a Hibernate PersistentSet) ?

```
System.out.println("size before " + runways.size());
Iterator<Runway> deleteIterator = runways.iterator();
while (deleteIterator.hasNext()) {
    Runway rwy = deleteIterator.next();
    if (rwy == rwy3) {
        System.out.println("remove !");
        deleteIterator.remove();
    }
}
System.out.println("size after " + runways.size());
```

I get the system.Out logs:

```
INFO: size before 3
INFO: remove !
INFO: size after 3
```

I thought that deletion through the iterator was safe and possible.
You see the log "remove"! which indicates that the remove() method is called.

EDIT : PersistentSet has problem with the remove method from the Iterator interface.

Comment: Can you show this in a short but *complete* example? (A similar version works for me...)

Comment: Hmmm... I just tried this and it worked as expected for me

Comment: Runways is a HashSet<Runway>

Comment: @Nicholas: The iterator would throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` if it didn't implement `remove`

Comment: I assume it is `java.util.Hashset`, right?

Comment: Your code works on my machine, although I do not know how your `Runway` class is implemented. Did you create some strange `equals` and/or `hashCode` methods in `Runway`?

Comment: Is that the full code ? *If the hashCode() value of an object has changed since it was added to the HashSet, it seems to render the object unremovable.*

Comment: Please show us the Runway code, in particular your `equals` and `hashCode` methods if you've overridden them.

Comment: I voted to close as the OP did not provide required information (`equals` and `hashCode`)...

Answer (score 3):

Check to make sure your `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods are overridden and correct on your `Runway` object.

Comment: He's seeing the `System.out` be called, which would indicate that he is already in the `if` block.

Comment: Since it enters the `if` block, this is not a problem.

Comment: No, this is a very relevant issue

Comment: @RobWatt I think I see what you are saying. The `HashMap$HashIterator`  class has the `remove()` method for the iterator, and that performs a remove based on the `hashCode()` and `equals()`, is that a valid assumption?

Comment: He enters the if block because he is using == which checks to see if it's the same instance of the class.  remove() uses .equals() which is different.

Comment: To further explain, there is no guarantee the List implementation uses == although it should.  Seems the problem IS related to the implementation of the List (see @user1446127 answer)

Answer (score 3):

***//EDIT: FYI this code is an example of failing code. Override your `equals()` and `hashCode()` properly.***

To follow up on JustinKSU's point, if you don't implement your `hashCode()` and `equals()` well, what you are doing won't work. I can replicate your situation if I muddy the `equals()` and the `hashCode()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Runway> runways = new HashSet<Runway>();
    Runway rwy1 = new Runway();
    Runway rwy2 = new Runway();
    Runway rwy3 = new Runway();
    runways.add(rwy1);
    runways.add(rwy2);
    runways.add(rwy3);
    System.out.println("size before " + runways.size());
    Iterator<Runway> deleteIterator = runways.iterator();
    while (deleteIterator.hasNext()) {
        Runway rwy = deleteIterator.next();
        if (rwy == rwy3) {
            System.out.println("remove !");
            deleteIterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("size after " + runways.size());
}

private static class Runway {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (new Random()).nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1; nice example! maybe you should add a **this code is wrong** disclaimer

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the JDK source code (I found it [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashSet.java?av=f)), the iterator returned by a `HashSet` uses one of the `HashSet`'s internal remove methods for performing the actual removal.

For a `HashSet` to work correctly, you need to either leave both `equals` and `hashCode` in your `Runway` class alone, or override them both. This SO question talks about this issue: [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

My equals and hashCode methodes were created by Eclipse itself. So it doesn't come from them.

But I was too quick at the beginning of my question. I forgot that Runways is a PersistentSet from Hibernate (and not a java.util.HashSet)

And I found this [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3799) which explaines why it is not possible to remove a object from a PersistenSet iterator.

The bug seems old and complicated to solve.
My only option is then to recreate a set from the first one, and without the element I don't want.